# Why does my accuracy score drop after hyperparameter tuning in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, scoring

I am trying to tune the model I've built, but every time I change hyperparameters my accuracy score drops significantly. I'm using RandomizedSearchCV and best_params_ to determine which parameters I need to change. In this specific case best_params_ recommends a learning rate of .29, while dropping the accuracy score from 0.6238 to 0.6192. The code I use to tune parameters is below:

```
xgb = XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', objective='multi:softmax', random_state=42, eval_metric="auc", 
                    num_class=num_of_classes, tree_method='gpu_hist', importance_type='gain')

xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)

params={
    "colsample_bytree":[1],
    "gamma":[0],
    "learning_rate":[0.3,0.29], 
    "max_delta_step":[0], 
    "max_depth":[6],
    "min_child_weight":[1],
    "n_jobs":[12],
    "subsample":[1]
    }

clf=RandomizedSearchCV(xgb,param_distributions=params,n_iter=1000,scoring='accuracy',cv=10,verbose=3)
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

And this is the code for measuring accuracy:

```
val = clf.predict(X_test)

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(y_test)

y_test_lb = lb.transform(y_test)
val_lb = lb.transform(val)

accuracy_score(y_test_lb, val_lb)
```